# Vim autocomplete как уменьшить размер подсказки

Tags: c++, vim, autocomplete, clang

У меня стоит *YouCompleteMe* (на *clang*). При автодополнении выходит панелька со списком функций и аргументами. Вроде все нормально. Пишу на *c++*.

Проблема в том, что если аргументов много, то они уходят за край экрана.

Также не пойму, как, например, посмотреть определение функции с аргументами, чтобы все время не лезть в документацию.

---

**EDIT:** на свои функции я могу посмотреть нажав <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>, но что делать, к примеру, с *STL* или сторонними библиотеками?

Comment: Согласно традициям русских форумов: хватит мучаться с vim, ставьте нормальный IDE! %)

Comment: мне там нравятся шрифты и фон ;D и работаю на виртуалке  - как то ИДЕ подтормаживать будет наверное. А какую можете посоветовать для c++?

Comment: Visual Studio + Visual Assist, Visual Studio + ReSharper C++, CLion, Qt Creator... Сейчас виртуалки шустрые, виртуализация скорость не убивает, поэтому проблем быть не должно. И уж точно скорость — не самый важный фактор при выборе среды. Впрочем, я не плюсовик, так, краем уха слышал.

Comment: @Discord это-то всё так, но если хорошо работается в Vim, то никакие монстры (в хорошем смысле), как CLion, не переубедят)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Открываем [репозиторий YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe), ищем в нём, находим [issue 166](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/166), в котором говорится выставить стандартное свойство vim-а `pumheight`. `:help pumheight` говорит, что это то, что надо.